# String variable obtained via php _$post from html form seems to be getting erased

Tags: php, string, forms, post

I am posting a string through an HTML form with the following code:

```
<html>
<body>
<form name="form" enctype="multipart/form-data" action="test.php" method="post">
         <input name="message" 
         type="text" value=""><br/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Upload"/><br/>
         </form>
         </body>
         </html>
```

The code for test.php is the following:

```
    <html>
   <head xmlns:testapp="https://apps.facebook.com/testapp/ns#">
     <title>Test App</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <?php
   echo "1".$_POST["message"];
   $string1 = $_POST["message"];
   echo "2".$string1;
  $app_id = "191622610935428";
  $app_secret = "a9cdd876cdaf17b6454639b19d91f157";
  $my_url = "http://www.thepropagator.com/facebook/worldcentric";
  $og_url = "http://thepropagator.com/facebook/worldcentric/issue.php?name=".$string1;
  $code = $_REQUEST["code"];

  if(empty($code)) {
    $dialog_url = "https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id="
    . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url) . "&scope=email,publish_actions";

    echo("<script>top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'</script>");
  }

  $token_url="https://graph.facebook.com/oauth/access_token?client_id="
  . $app_id . "&redirect_uri=" . urlencode($my_url)
  . "&client_secret=" . $app_secret
  . "&code=" . $code;

  $access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);

  // remove the @expires
  $params = null;
  parse_str($access_token, $params);
  $access_token_updated = $params['access_token'];

  $post_data = "issue=" . $og_url . "&access_token=" . $access_token_updated;

  echo "post_data: " . $post_data . "<br/>";

  // setup the POST
  $ch = curl_init();

  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,'https://graph.facebook.com/me/testapp:raise?issue');
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $post_data);

  // execute the POST
  $result = curl_exec ($ch);
  if(curl_error($ch))
  {
    echo 'error:' . curl_error($ch) . "<br/>";
  }
  curl_close ($ch);

  echo "return code= " . $result . "<br/>";

   ?>
   <br>
   </br>
   </body>
 </html>
```

When I hit submit of the form the echos I do in the first block of code show the posted strings as expected but at some point they disappear and the variable $og_url looses the concatenated string .$string1. It seems like at some point this variable is getting erased can anyone explain why this is happening?

The only line that generates a PHP error is :
    $access_token = file_get_contents($token_url);
And I'm pretty sure the only reason for the error is because there is nothing after"name=" in the string $og_url.

It seems that my problem is being caused by the line of code.
    echo("top.location.href='" . $dialog_url . "'");

However I'm not sure why and I can't just get rid of the line.

Comment: The syntax of this code is invalid, and there seems to be a lot of nonsense in there, like `$og_url.test`. Activate error reporting (`error_reporting(E_ALL); ini_set('display_errors', true);`) and do some step by step debugging.

Comment: I have removed the line you mentioned and consulted the error_log (see code changes), but the root problem of the string variable $string1 getting erased before the line $access_token = file_get_contents($token_url); still seems to be there.

Answer (score 0):

You should turn on php notices and read your error log, but I strongly suspect this line is implicated:

```
$og_url = $og_url.test;
```

Comment: I have removed this line (reflected in posted code) and my problem persists.

Answer (score 0):

As the SO formatting shows this looks wrong

```
name=".$_Post["message"];
  name=".$string1;
```

I'm not quite sure what your trying to do. From the look of it I'm surprised it even executes with errors.

Comment: I have removed these line (see code changes) and the problem persists.